# OpenCV- Webcam frame not working on macbook in Java

Tags: java, macos, opencv, webcam

I just waded through my first install of opencv on my mac air, and I've been trying to get input out of the camera built into the screen. So far as I can tell, I have the libraries running in Eclipse correctly, as I no longer get massive errors every time I try to call any of the methods. However, what is happening now is a problem with the webcam, which seems to be correctly created with 0 passed to the constructor (nothing else from 1-50 returns anything, and -1 I believe is the default). But when I try to use it to get a frame back, the mat is always empty.

As far as I can tell, it seems like I'm able to access the camera, but theres some sort of disconnect going on between the code and being able to actually activate the camera to take video. If it matters at all, the light that shows the camera active for most programs has always remained inactive.

The relevant code is posted below. I would greatly appreciate any insight you may have or examples of code working in java to get an image out of a webcam for use in a java gui. Thanks!

```
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //camera.open(0); //Useless
    if(!camera.isOpened()){
        System.out.println("Camera broken");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Camera OK!");
    }

    Mat frame = new Mat();

    camera.read(frame);

    System.out.println("width:" + frame.width());

    Highgui.imwrite("myframe.png", frame);
```

The output is:

```
Camera OK!
width:0
libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
Cleaned up camera.
```

Comment: I had something similar on Windows and Linux, all I had to do was to change the index in the `VideoCapture` call. You say that indices from 1-50 return nothing. Could you say what happens exactly? I noticed that sometimes I need to close all other programs using the camera and what didn't work previously then works.

Comment: Hm, I'll give that a shot, and try to restart everything and try to run from scratch, which will have to wait until tonight unfortunately. When I tried to open 0-50 and then check to see if camera.isopen(), it returned that none but the 0-slot was opened. So I assumed that the others were reserved for having other cameras, which makes sense. I should not that I've had some luck running https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture which lets me get back an image, but its in pretty bad quality and I'd really like to keep it all in openCV.

Comment: Yes, openCV is already not exactly straightforward so adding even more libraries on top might not help :P I've never used openCV in java but I can write you an example piece of code in python which will go through all cameras and try to take a picture, perhaps you can work from there and reproduce it in java. But do try shutting everything down and rebooting, it might just work as it did for me :D

Answer (score 0):

it's been a while since this question was asked, but since I had essentially the same problem, I will post a solution (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835424/opencv-2-4-4-java-grab-webcam-picture-stream-osx)) (it's a rather simple fix actually for a stupid problem):

The camera needs time to initialize (not sure what the gory hardware details are, but there you go). To fix it I simply added Thread.sleep(1000), and it started working. A slightly better fix may be to wrap this in a loop which retries every 1000ms or so until the returned Mat is not empty.

Hope someone benefits from this :-)

EDIT: I should have read your code first. Silly me, apologies. The problem seemed very similar to mine, so I assumed it was the same.