# Import opencv to use with java

Tags: java, macos, opencv, jar

I'm trying to include the openCV library on a little java [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835424/opencv-2-4-4-java-grab-webcam-picture-stream-osx). Since I'm not using any IDE, I compile using the following command:

```
$ javac -cp $CLASSPATH:/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12/share/OpenCV/java/opencv-2412.jar Webcam.java
```

(I installed openCV using brew)

and it compiles just fine, but the moment I run it, throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java2412 in java.library.path
```

from this line:

```
System.loadLibrary("opencv_java2412");
```

Could somebody help me?

----- EDIT -----

I've also tried using:

```
$ export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12/share/OpenCV/java/opencv-2412.jar
```

then:

```
$ javac Webcam.java
$ java Webcam
```

getting the same result

Comment: What command are you using to run your program?  Are you making sure that opencv-2412.jar is on your classpath at runtime, as well as at compile time?

Comment: Just 'java Webcam' :o how do I add it at runtime?

Comment: Did your opencv installation come with some sort of native library for use at runtime?  I notice that the jar is called `opencv-2412.jar`, but the library you're trying to load is `opencv_java2412`.  Try looking around in your OpenCV directory for a lib directory or something?

Comment: If that doesn't work, I'm out of ideas.  I hope someone with more mac/osx knowledge comes along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solve it loading the lib directly from the code, replacing:

```
System.loadLibrary("opencv_java2412");
```

with

```
System.load("/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.12/share/OpenCV/java/libopencv_java2412.dylib");
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the accepted answer does work, but I've just run into this problem too and thought I should write down what I did. I installed OpenCV with Homebrew too, so my libraries are in the same place as above.

Yes, you need to set the java.library.path, e.g. (I'm using OpenCV 3.1.0 here):

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/share/OpenCV/java
```

In the code examples I've seen the library is loaded in Java:

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

Where Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME resolves to "opencv_java310". The native library names its actually looking for are:

```
libopencv_java310.dylib
```

or if that's not found then:

```
libopencv_java310.jnilib
```

However, Homebrew only provided libopencv_java310.so and needed a symbolic link:

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/share/OpenCV/java

ln -s libopencv_java310.so libopencv_java310.dylib
```

After that things started working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -Djava.library.path=PATH_TO_YOUR_LIBS options
Actually, you can unpack .so files (libs) and set path to this libraries.